# Error while using Matlab logical operators and tables

Tags: matlab, operators, cell, logical-operators

I am trying to use a very simple logical argument using the following code:

```
for i=1:size(A)
    if A.VariableName(i)==0
        flag=1;
        break
    end
end
```

however I get the following error:

```
Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this strange issue?

Comment: Can you post what `A` is?

Comment: Regardless of what `A` is, why are you comparing a string (presumably) to `0`?

Comment: I'd also suggest reading MATLAB's [indexing documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/indexing.html), noting the differences between indexing matrices and indexing cell arrays.

Comment: `A` is a 98004x36 table.

`Name` is just to represent for VariableName. (I just edited my post)

Comment: @manosbar again, note the differences in indexing notation in the linked documentation. Arrays, including cell arrays, are indexed with `()`. To index the *contents* of a cell in a cell array you need to use `{}`.

Comment: Since `A` is a table, have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html If your column contains strings, using `.var()` indexing returns a cell (of strings) (because your index might access several rows)